# Hiding content on view, based on controller authorization filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have a controller action that is restricted to only certain users, like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles="somerole")]<br />
public ActionResult TestRestricted()  {            
    return View();
}
```

On a view, that is public to everyone I have a link to the action defined above:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Click here!", "TestRestricted") %>
```

What I'd like to do is hide the link for everyone that is not allowed perform the "TestRestricted"-action. Is there a way to check if the current user is authorized to use the corresponding action? Without defining any additional or duplicate access rules in addition to the authorization filter?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the MVC framework that can control permissions at such a granular level.

**First Approach**

This is by far the easiest approach. The drawback is having to assign the role to each action link.

What you could do, is write a Action HtmlHelper to control the permissions at a link level. Make sure you include the namespace `System.Web.Mvc.Html`.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string role)
    {
        MvcHtmlString link = new MvcHtmlString(string.Empty);

        if (htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(role))
        {
            link = htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName);
        }

        return link;
    }

<%= Html.ActionLink("Click here!", "TestRestricted", "somerole") %>
```

**Second Approach**

You could use reflection to discover the action(method) being called. Once discovered a simple check of the attributes would tell you if the authorize attribute was present and what role it was set too.

Answer (score 1):

This may help: http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/09/06/asp-net-mvc-and-authorization-and-monkey-patching.aspx

I am also trying to find an answer to this question.....